# Stopping an upstart script not working

Tags: upstart

When I try: `stop mysite_api`, I get:

```
stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.11" (uid=1000 pid=2242 comm="stop mysite_api ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

My script is:

```
description "Mysite API Server"
author "Mysite"

start on vagrant-mounted
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

script
    cd /vagrant/Mysite/api
    exec sudo -u vagrant python api.py
end script
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an answer yet, but I can edit later. What happens if you change your script to this:

```
description "Mysite API Server"
author "Mysite"

start on vagrant-mounted
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

setuid vagrant
chdir /vagrant/Mysite/api

exec python api.py
```

Comment: I guess it was good enough.